# Induction proof: $n! > (\frac{n}{2})^\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: induction, factorial

> Prove that: $n! > (\frac{n}{2})^\frac{n}{2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Using induction:

Base case: $1! > (\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{2}$

Assume that $n! > (\frac{n}{2})^\frac{n}{2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now we have to show that $(n+1)! > (\frac{n+1}{2})^\frac{n+1}{2}$

$$(n+1)! = n! (n+1) > (n+1) \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^\frac{n}{2}$$

I unfortunately stop there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It remains to show that
$$(n+1) \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^\frac{n}{2}\geq \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^\frac{n+1}{2}$$
that is, after squaring,
$$2(n+1)^2(n)^n\geq (n+1)^{n+1}$$
or
$$2n+2\geq \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}.$$
Can you take it form here?